# how to create cordova project using php

Tags: php, android, ios, cordova

I have installed cordova, php, android, and ios in my machine.
I can create cordova project using command-line successfully.
I need to create cordova project using php script. Here I have did something but couldn't get success.

```
<?php
  try {
    $responsecode = '';
    $command = 'cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld';
    exec($command,$responsecode);
    echo $responsecode;
  }
  catch(Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
  }  
?>
```

when i execute this script I got response code 127. 127 code indicate command not found. I have added all the paths in environment variable but still I am not able to create cordova project using php script.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching regarding this issue I found the solution.
We need to add command library to our project using "putenv" function in php.

```
putenv('PATH='. getenv('PATH') .':/usr/local/bin');
```

Use this function before command execute

```
try {

    putenv('PATH='. getenv('PATH') .':/usr/local/bin');
    exec('cordova -v 2>&1', $output);

    print_r($output);


}
catch(Exception $ex) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($ex);
}
```